# jQuery condition applied to multiple items

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements, each

I am trying to #1 get the file extension and then once I have that -conditionally display a corresponding icon to show what file type it is. I got it to detect the extension, I got it to work the first time, I can't get it to treat each item differently.

Here is the code:

```
   <html>
<head>
<title>check ext</title>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){


$("div").each(function(){ 
var fileName =$('div img.myimg').attr('src')
var fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') );



if (fileExtension==".jpg")
{
   $(this).next().find("#indicator").addClass("isjpg");
}
else (fileExtension==".gif")
{
   $(this).next().find("#indicator").addClass("isgif");

}


 });



 });

</script>

<style>
.isjpg{background-image:url('images/jpg.gif');}
.isgif{background-image:url('images/gif.gif');}

#indicator{width:100px;height:100px;border:solid;border-width:1px;}
</style>



</head>
<body>
<div>
<img class="myimg" src="images/carthumb.jpg"/><div id="indicator"></div>
</div>

<div>
<img class="myimg" src="images/plus.gif"/><div id="indicator"></div>
</div>
<div>
<img class="myimg" src="images/carthumb.jpg"/><div id="indicator"></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ^i.e. html id's should be unique :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `this` to reference the current `<div>` in the iteration sequence, otherwise the filename returned will always be that indicated by the image in the first div:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body > div").each(function() {
        var fileName = $(this).find('img.myimg').attr('src');
        var fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));

        if (fileExtension == ".jpg") {
            $(this).find("#indicator").addClass("isjpg");
        }
        else if (fileExtension == ".gif") {
            $(this).find("#indicator").addClass("isgif");
        }
    });
});
```

i.e. change <del>`var fileName =$('div img.myimg').attr('src')`</del> to this `var fileName =$(this).find('img.myimg').attr('src');`

To be clever and avoid checking each one, you can do this (to replace your `if/else`):

```
if(fileExtension)
    $(this).find("#indicator").addClass("is" + fileExtension.slice(1) );
```

Notice that I removed [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), it was targeting the *next* div.

Comment: won't work.. `$(this).next()`.. you need to traverse inside the div to get the `#indicator` div.. Plus `$("div")` will grab the inner divs

Comment: @nbrooks also one more thing.. `else` does not allow a condition.. you have to use `else if` for that

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the following line to reference the correct object.

```
var fileName =$(this).find('img.myimg').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shorter way to do it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body > div").each(function() {  // <-- get div's that are direct descendants of body
        var fileName = $(this).find('.myimg').attr('src'); // <-- find img and get src   
        var fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));  // <-- get img file type
        $(this).find('div').addClass('is'+fileExtension.replace('.','')); // add class 'is' + file type without period
        // since there is only one div you can just look for the div.. 
        // ID's should be unique.. you can change it to a class  or data- attribute if you 
        // really need more than one
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/4L7wB/

Comment: WOW that was great, plus, poking around I found this: http://cool-javascripts.com/jquery/add-icons-to-your-links-automatically-using-jquery-css.html BUT again, thank you! I have alot of basics down but I'm still new to a few things. BUT all around I like this solution better.

Comment: @namretiolnave with jQuery it'll only get more fun :)

Comment: both : $(this).find('div').addClass('is'+fileExtension.replace('.','')); AND if(fileExtension)
    $(this).find("#indicator").addClass("is" + fileExtension.slice(1) );
will work -does anyone know WHY the jQuery didn't like  the "if" and "else" conditional?

Comment: @namretiolnave Yes.  You have an `if/else` condition.. `else` shouldn't have any conditions.  You should be using `if/else if` the way you have it set up